# Java + Pa11y + login web page

Tags: pa11y

I am a beginner to Pa11y. The web application on which I am working needs user login. Once the user logs in then then only the rest of the pages are visible.

Any idea how can I use pa11y to login to the web page and run pa11y on those pages using java ?

We use java in pur project. Is ther any way to achieve this using java and how?

Your help is much appreciated as I could not find any example on internet which uses java + pa11y + web page login

Answer (score 2):

Pa11y is a NodeJS application that spins up an instance of a headless browser, injects some JavaScript into the rendered page, then runs a series of tests against that rendered page. It doesn't interact in any way with the server-side technology of your website, so that's why you can't find instructions for using Pa11y with Java.

The Pa11y documentation explains how to log into a webpage using basic auth or through the site's login form. See [How can Pa11y log in if my site's behind basic auth?](https://github.com/pa11y/pa11y/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#how-can-pa11y-log-in-if-my-sites-behind-basic-auth) and [How can Pa11y log in if my site has a log in form?](https://github.com/pa11y/pa11y/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#how-can-pa11y-log-in-if-my-site-has-a-log-in-form)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply @hollsk

Another approach is below. With this approach I can use selenium and Pa11y with my existing automation framework. Steps below can be clubbed in a java function and can be called with my selenium tests.

1. Navigate to the page through Selenium and Perform authentication
2. Capture the page source and save it as .html file
3. Run Pally html reporter on the html file saved in step 2 and collect the result
4. Stpes 1-3 can be repeated for the pages for which accessibility testing needs to be performed

Can you please provide your feedback on this approach?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Pa11y isn't really designed to be used that way - you might find it easier to switch to axe and use their Selenium webdriver API instead: https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-selenium-java